# Conflict with "System.Runtime" after updating Microsoft Graph NuGet package

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, nuget-package, visual-studio-2022

I just updated my Microsoft Graph to the latest version and now I get a compiler warning:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: OutlookCalIFConsole, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Restored D:\My Programs\2022\OutlookCalIFConsole\OutlookCalIFConsole\OutlookCalIFConsole.csproj (in 61 ms).
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Runtime" that could not be resolved.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277: There was a conflict between "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:     "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.runtime\4.3.1\ref\net462\System.Runtime.dll].
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:         C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.runtime\4.3.1\ref\net462\System.Runtime.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.runtime\4.3.1\ref\net462\System.Runtime.dll".
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.runtime\4.3.1\ref\net462\System.Runtime.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:         C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.4\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.4\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll".
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.4\ref\net46\System.Net.Http.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.22.0\lib\net461\Azure.Core.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.30.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.8\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identity.client\4.44.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.logging\6.15.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens\6.15.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols\6.15.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.openidconnect\6.15.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.identitymodel.tokens\6.15.1\lib\net461\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt\6.15.1\lib\net461\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.net.http.winhttphandler\6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:         C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll".
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\azure.core\1.22.0\lib\net461\Azure.Core.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph\4.30.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.dll
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ajtru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.graph.core\2.0.8\lib\net462\Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll
```

In my `App.config` I do have:

```
  <dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

What is the correct way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I simply deleted the system.runtime from app.config

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out, there is conflict between `System.Runtime,Version=4.1.1.1` the `Version=4.1.2.0` and You can try by `update-package -reinstall` , hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks. When I ran that command it said : `PM> update-package -reinstall
The -Reinstall parameter does not apply to PackageReference based projects '..\OutlookCalIFConsole\OutlookCalIFConsole\OutlookCalIFConsole.csproj'.`

Comment: Please try to uninstall manually ,Uninstall-Package System.Runtime -Force  and install-Package System.Runtime -Version 4.1.2.0

Comment: As I already mentioned in the comment I made to my question, simply deleting the line from my `app.config` stopped the problem. So I am assuming it is now OK. I get no build errors.

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix it from my side was to remove the `System.Runtime` nuget dependency from my project; the error was gone and the app still works.